# Extracting indices of feature from multidimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization, array-broadcasting

I have an array representing the values of cloud water concentration in three dimensional space. At places where the cloud water concentration is above some threshold I say that I have a cloud (see the cross section below). Most of the domain is dry, but there is a stratocumulus cloud across most of the domain with base at around 400 meters.

[image: Cloud cross section]

What I want to do is extract the (x,y,z) coordinates of cloud base and cloud top. Then I want to use these coordinates on a different three dimensional array representing the vertical component of the windspeed to get the updraft at cloud base.

What I am doing right now works but is slow. I feel like there must be a way to take advantage of NumPy to speed it up.

This is what I am doing now:

```
# 3d array representing cloud water at a particular timestep t
qc = QC(t)

# get the coordinates where there is cloud
cloud_coords = argwhere( qc > qc_thresh )

# Arrays to hold the z values of cloud base (cb) and cloud top (ct)
zcb = zeros((nx,ny))
zct = zeros((nx,ny))

# Since each coordinate (x,y) will in general have multiple z values
# for cloud I have to loop over all (x,y) and
# pull out max and min height for each point (x,y)
for x in range(nx):
    # Pull out all the coordinates with a given x value
    xslice = cloud_coords[ where(cloud_coords[:,0] == x) ]

    for y in range(ny):       
        # for the given x value select a particular y value
        column = xslice[ where(xslice[:,1] == y) ]

        try:
            zcb[x,y] = min( column[:,2] )
            zct[x,y] = max( column[:,2] )
        except:
            # Because there may not be any cloud at all
            # (a "hole") we fill the array with an average value
            zcb[x,y] = mean(zcb[zcb.nonzero()])
            zct[x,y] = mean(zct[zct.nonzero()])


# Because I intend to use these as indices I need them to be ints
zcb = array(zcb, dtype='int')
zct = array(zct, dtype='int')
```

The output is a two dimensional array containing the z coordinates of cloud base (and top)

[image: Cloud base height]

I then use these indices on another array to get variables like windspeed at cloud base:

```
wind = W(t)
j,i = meshgrid(arange(ny),arange(nx))
wind_base = wind[i,j,zcb]
```

I do this for many timesteps in the simulation and the slowest part is the python loop over all the (x,y) coordinates. Any help on using NumPy to extract these values faster would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your suspicion that numpy can be put to good use with your problem is correct. Actually, there are multiple inefficiencies you're doing, for instance explicitly creating a new array using `np.array()` at the end, and one with a `dtype` of `int` which is a complex object in python 3.

You can do most of the work in a few vectorized lines of numpy. The idea is that it's enough to find the indices (along the height axis) where a cloud appears, or where a cloud ends. We can do that in a vectorized way using [`numpy.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html). That's really the heart of an efficient solution:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate dummy data
qc_thresh = 0.6
nx,ny,nz = 400,400,100
qc = np.zeros((nx,ny,nz))
# insert random cloud layer
qc[...,50:80] = np.random.rand(nx,ny,30)
# insert holes in clouds for completeness
qc[np.random.randint(nx,size=2*nx),np.random.randint(ny,size=2*nx),:] = 0

def compute_cloud_boundaries():
    cloud_arr = qc > qc_thresh

    # find boundaries by making use of np.argmax returning first maximum
    zcb = np.argmax(cloud_arr,axis=-1)
    zct = nz - 1 - np.argmax(cloud_arr[...,::-1],axis=-1)

    # logical (nx,ny)-shaped array where there's a cloud
    cloud_inds = (zcb | (zct!=nz-1)).astype(bool)
    # this is short for `(zcb==0) | (zct!=nz-1)`

    # fill the rest with the mean
    zcb[np.logical_not(cloud_inds)] = zcb[cloud_inds].mean()
    zct[np.logical_not(cloud_inds)] = zct[cloud_inds].mean()

    return zcb,zct
```

I checked the above (complete with the corresponding small example) against your approach, and it gives the exact same result. As I said, the idea is that `cloud_arr = qc > qc_thresh` is a logical array telling us where the humidity is large enough to qualify for a cloud. Then we look at the maximum of this (essentially binary!) matrix along the last (height) axis. Calling `np.argmax` will tell us the first (bottommost) height value for each planar 2d index. In order to get the top of the clouds, we need to reverse our array
and do the same from the other side (taking care of transforming back the resulting indices). Reversing the array creates a view rather than a copy, so this is efficient too. Finally, we correct the points where there are no clouds; in lieu of a better constraint we check where the highest index returned by `argmax` corresponds to the edge point. Considering realistic weather data, we can be sure that the bottommost and topmost measurements do *not* correspond to clouds, so this should be a safe criterion.

Here's a cross-section of the dummy data for show:

[image: simulated result]

Non-representative timings for the above `400x400x100` case:

```
In [24]: %timeit compute_cloud_boundaries()
10 loops, best of 3: 29.1 ms per loop

In [25]: %timeit orig() # original loopy version from the question
1 loop, best of 3: 9.37 s per loop
```

That seems to be more than a 300-fold increase in speed. Of course your actual use case will be the proper test of this approach, but it should be fine.

---

As for the indexing step, you could spare some memory by using an open grid for the indices and making use of array broadcasting. Not having to allocate additional `(nx,ny)`-shaped arrays might speed up this step a bit too:

```
wind = W(t)
i,j = np.ogrid[:nx,:ny]
wind_base = wind[i,j,zcb]
```

As you can see, `np.ogrid` creates an open grid of shape `(nx,1)` and `(1,ny)` that broadcast together to what is equivalent to the `meshgrid` call.